# Boss attacks for a purple worm

Tags: biology, creature-design, physics, weapons, dungeons

I am making a boss fight themed quest in Dungeons and Dragons, and I am having trouble coming up with "Boss Attacks" that would be physically possible as well as add diversity to the purple worms attacks. I want it to have something other than the base attacks in its stat block. Here are the original stats for the worm. https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16987-purple-worm. The fight will take place in a 50 meter diameter cylindrical chamber with a height of 20 meters. The walls are smoothly carved stone carved by the purple worms burrowing over time. The chamber has a blanket antimagic field that disrupts magic items, and stops spells entirely. Given these parameters, what attacks would you suggest for a 7th level party to face?

Comment: I believe there is a DnD stackexchange. I feel they might be better equipped to answer that question

Comment: @HarryMu are you thinking of https://rpg.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @candied_orange yea that one

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like it's locked in DND5E and thus is best answered in RPG.SE.

Comment: @HarryMu There's a sizable contingent you don't want to catch you calling us the "D&D StackExchange", it's up to a quite sore point :)

Comment: For future ref for WB -> RPG migrations, please be aware we have *very* different standards on idea gen gathering and what problems to be solved are expected to look like.

Comment: @Someone_Evil
Sorry haha, outside of searching for answers in physics SE and giving answers in WB-SE, I didn't know that much about other SE's in general lol. ( truth be told I did take a wild guess and surmised that there would be a place in SE for DnD folks and bluffed that I knew of one.)

Answer (score 2):

Swallow the players. Writhe around and hit them all at once. Throw them them into walls. This might knock them prone or daze them. Burrow underground so the worm is hard to hit. Then attack from below. Throw up dust clouds to blind the player.

Try to capture the fact that a fight with a giant purple worm is not the same as a fight with another person. The worm does not stand at the other side of the room and exchange blows. The worm fills the entire room. Its head towers over you and its coils surround you.

Maybe you have to climb on the worm to hit it. In that case it can throw you off. Or maybe it has poisonous spikes to stab the players, or to use as handholds.

Poison blood. When you cut the worm with your longsword, you get drenched in it's caustic blood and have to make a Con save against purple worm STIs.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this. As to the others, I did not know there was an rpg stack exchange.

Comment: You're welcome. You might like to know that many people have tried to flesh out the rules for climbing on big monsters. [For example.](https://2minutetabletop.com/colossal-creatures-ruleset/)

Comment: That is helpful.